# Analogs for Placeholder from Django-CMS or Streamfield from Wagtail without cms itself

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, django-cms, wagtail-streamfield

I often need to implement rich content editing in my django projects. There are a lot of different wysiwyg-editors, but they are not good for creating complex content structure. Placeholder from Django-CMS or Streamfield from Wagtail can do it much better, but I don't want to add whole CMS to my project, because it brings a lot of unnecessary stuff into interface.

All I need is just a field with ordered list of widgets inside + editing interface for it. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I thing you should reconsider your dismissal of CMS options. Wagtail (and I am assuming DCMS) can be easily integrated in whole or in part in your project. I would personally use wagtail, and just render the "page" within a certain element as needed. Plus, the backed is so user and developer friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django CMS is very modular - you do not need to bring in the whole URL and page management interface.

You can enhance your existing models with Django CMS's placeholder fields and use the rich structure mode and plugins only, for example:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # your fields
    my_placeholder = PlaceholderField('placeholder_name')
    # your methods
```

Example taken from  [Django CMS documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/placeholders.html).